# PHPMAILER - do I need to initialize it every time I send a mail?

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

I use PHPMailer to send Emails. 
Now I need to send multiple different emails at a point of my application.

So first i do the frist email

- initalize PHPMailer
- fill FROM/ADRESS/BODY
- send it

now the second email

- initalize PHPMailer
- fill FROM/ADRESS/BODY
- send it

my question is, do I really have to initialize the PHPMailer for every email? Or is there a other method to reset all previous ADRESS-field i.e. ?

Comment: Take a look at the mailing list example provided with PHPMailer. It shows how to reuse an instance efficiently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the same PHPMailer object again, you can use the [clear-methods](https://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.html) of PHPMailer, e.g. the [clearAdresses-method](https://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.html#method_clearAddresses) or [clearAllRecipients-method](https://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.html#method_clearAllRecipients):

```
$yourphpmailer->clearAddresses();
```